# retropie 4.8 display doesn't work when connected to AV Receiver (Sony STR-DH770)

Tags: display, retropie, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I just rebuilt my retropie and confirmed its worked fine when connected to a standard 1080p computer monitor or when connected directly to my tv.  However, when I connect it to my AV receiver (Sony STR-DH770) which connects to my TV, the display doesn't work.  I'm using the same cables, and I can ssh to it while its on, and I've tried all of the 4 HDMI input ports on the back of the AV receiver (and they all work for all other devices like roku, xbox, etc...).  I just cannot get the pi's HDMI display to work when going thru my receiver to the tv?

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: replace the cable between the stereo receiver and the TV ... are you certain that the stereo receiver is able to output video?

Comment: @jsotola - everything else connected to the receiver works fine, i.e. roku, exbox, etc...

Comment: Is the receiver set to the proper source input?

Comment: yes, "I've tried all of the 4 HDMI input ports on the back that work for other devices (roku, xbox, etc...)"

Comment: I never figured out the problem here, but this seems to have made things work again https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00XJITK7E?psc=1